"missing value for command" error in terraform code
I see the following error while executing terraform plan.
If I delete the .terraform* files, terraform plan works. If I run terraform apply after this, terraform apply again fails with the same error.
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.
│ Error: template: .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/akamai/akamai/6.0.0/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-akamai_v6.0.0:70761: missing value for command
│ 
│   with data.akamai_property_rules_template.rules,
│   on akamai.tf line 54, in data "akamai_property_rules_template" "rules":
│   54: data "akamai_property_rules_template" "rules" {

This is my code.
data "akamai_property_rules_template" "rules" {
  template_file = abspath("${path.root}/property-rules.json")
  variables {
    name = "directory_name"
    value = var.directory_name
    type = "string"
  }
}

property-rules.json
{
  "rules": {
    "name": "default",
    "behaviors": [
      {
        "name": "origin",
        "options": {
          "originType": "NET_STORAGE",
          "netStorage": {
            "cpCode": 1111111,
            "downloadDomainName": "testnsx.download.akamai.com",
            "name": "TestNSx",
            "id": 0000000
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "allowPost",
        "options": {
          "allowWithoutContentLength": false,
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "caching",
        "options": {
          "behavior": "MAX_AGE"
        }
      }
    ],
    "variables": [
      {
        "name": "PMUSER_DIR",
        "value": "${env.directory_name}",
        "description": "Main content directory",
        "hidden": false,
        "sensitive": false
      },
      {
        "name": "PMUSER_FORCE_HTTPS",
        "value": "Y",
        "description": "Force secure connection",
        "hidden": false,
        "sensitive": false
      }
    ],
    "comments": "The behaviors in the Default Rule apply to all requests for the property hostname(s) unless another rule overrides the Default Rule settings."
  }
}

Any suggestions on how this could be fixed?

I'm not familiar with this Terraform provider, but it appears to be trying to render your template_file using Go's template engine, and that error comes from the template engine, so you might get better responses if you ask this as a Go programming language question and share the contents of property-rules.json instead of sharing your Terraform configuration.

Thank you for the suggestion @MartinAtkins. I added the property-rules.json to the question.

I work within the Akamai Terraform team.
The error states the rules are missing a required argument. Check your JSON file against the requirements. If you're still having issues, please open an issue in our Terraform provider repo.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
